# Why React Navigation event "willFocus" not executing?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have created some tabs using react-navigation v2 in react native app. I have created componentDidMount function in which willFocus is called. First time app runs and my desired tab is selected first time, willFocus is not executing. But when I go to different tab and comes back to that tab now willFocus executes. What is the reason willFocus not executes first time and works fine on second time?

Desired tab componentDidMount function

```js
componentDidMount(){
    const {navigation} = this.props;
    navigation.addListener ('willFocus', async () =>{
      console.log("willFocus runs"
    });
}
```

Tab navigator is nested with other navigators but i am only showing the tab navigator below

```js
TabNav: createBottomTabNavigator(
        {
            TAB1: Screen1,
            TAB2: Screen2,
            TAB3: Screen3,
            TAB4: Screen4,
            TAB5: Screen5,
            // Map: MapScreen
        },
        {
            initialRouteName: 'Bar',
            transitionConfig: NavigationConfig,
            navigationOptions: ({navigation})=>({
                tabBarIcon: ({focused, tintColor})=>{
                    const { routeName } = navigation.state;
                    let iconName, iconSize;
                    switch(routeName) {
                                case "TAB1":
                                    iconName = `icon1`;
                                    break;
                                case "TAB2":
                                    iconName = `icon2`;
                                    break;
                                case "TAB3":
                                    iconName = `icon3`;
                                    break;
                                case "TAB4":
                                    iconName = `icon4`;
                                    break;
                                case "TAB5":
                                    iconName = `icon5`;
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                                }
                    return <Icon name={iconName} color={tintColor} type="FontAwesome" />;
                },
            }),
            tabBarOptions: {
                activeTintColor: 'black',
                inactiveTintColor: 'grey',
                activeBackgroundColor: '#abaf9b',
                labelStyle: {
                    fontSize: 12,
                },
                // style for tabbar
                style: {
                    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
                    height: 60,
                    justifyContent: 'space-around',
                    alignContent: 'center',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                },
                // style for tab
                tabStyle: {
                    paddingTop: 7,
                    paddingBottom: 7
                }
            },
        }
    ),
```

Answer (score 8):

I had also this issue and it was reported as a bug fo react-navigation. Check [this](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3446) issue for details.

I have two suggestions to solve the issue.

1. Try to update react-navigation and check if the issue is solved
2. If first solution didnt work, as a workaround I am calling function two times, if you want to be sure that function is called both at initial start of the app and on screen changes.

PS:Check your function again and make sure that calling the function two times doesnt cause any side problems

```
componentDidMount(){
    console.log("willFocus runs") // calling it here to make sure it is logged at initial start

    const {navigation} = this.props;
    navigation.addListener ('willFocus', async () =>{
      console.log("willFocus runs") // calling it here to make sure it is logged at every time screen is focused after initial start
    });
}
```

Comment: Currently I am using same approach but drawback is that if there is a api call then it will call 2 times unnecessarily

Comment: "..navigation.addListener ('willFocus', **async** () =>{" ... this was the missing part for me! I had to use "async" in the listener! Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

i was having this issue because i had lazy: true in my tab navigators which was causing this issue. i removed it and now it is working on the first click as well.

Comment: You could use some markup and make it more structured.